# How to use images on my website from my computer

Tags: html

I want to be able to use my pictures on my computer and put it into my html code .

I have done this but on my website it comes up as broken image.

How would I do it so that other people would be able to see the images on my website.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some example of code? Have you tried uploading images to server?

Comment: You can't. You need to upload the image on the server which your website hosted in.

Comment: How would I do that as I'm using a free domain        000webhost

Comment: PerunSS - I will put a copy of the code on here as soon as I get back from work thank you both for you help .

Comment: Would I transfer the pictures over FileZilla to my domain in same folder as html file ?

Comment: post an example of how you coded the image. eg:  image/something.jpg

Comment: you should upload pictures as well as you uploaded the html file

Comment: <div  class="plastering">
             <h2>Plastering</h2>
             <h3>Thease are pictures of my stud walling :- </h3>
              <img src="/IMG_0022.JPG" alt="stud walling" height="260px" width="200px" />
              <img src="C:\Users\Trudy\Desktop\kj building solutions\html page (in code)\IMG_0026.JPG" alt="stud walling" height="260px" width="200px" />
              <img src="C:\Users\Trudy\Desktop\kj building solutions\html page (in code)\IMG_0036.JPG" alt="stud walling" height="260px" width="200px" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you can't see your image without upload it.It's normal to see as a broken image.So you have to upload it.Filezilla will help you to upload it into your server.After you upload it change your local img path to server img path and it will fix your problem.No need to upload on the same folder but just upload it into your server

Comment: how do i make it a sever img path

Comment: im using 000webhost

Comment: Firstly you have to upload your image into your server with Filezilla or whatever you want to use.So when you upload it,you will see your path like http:\\www.asdf.com\ımg_0026 or something like that.So copy that path into your html file.